# Many compilation errors after importing DOTS editor

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-dots

I'm trying to learn how to use DOTS, and I can't seem to get it to compile in a blank project.

I installed the following packages into a new unity project using editor version 2021.3.6f1:

```
com.unity.entities 0.51.1-preview.21
com.unity.rendering.hybrid 0.51.1-preview.21
com.unity.dots.editor 0.12.0-preview.6
```

Most of the (999+) compilation errors are file conflicts between the dots editor and the entities package, on top of some accessibility errors and some general other compilation errors.

One example of a conflict is:

```
GUID [0f14985c7cd188246a215cae5e2919a6] for asset 'Packages/com.unity.dots.editor/Runtime/Unity.InternalAPIEngineBridge.002/Unity.InternalAPIEngineBridge.002.asmdef' conflicts with: 'Packages/com.unity.entities/Unity.Entities.Editor/Unity.InternalAPIEngineBridge.002/Unity.InternalAPIEngineBridge.002.asmdef' (current owner) We can't assign a new GUID because the asset is in an immutable folder. The asset will be ignored.
```

And an example of an accessibility error is:

```
Library\PackageCache\com.unity.dots.editor@0.12.0-preview.6\Editor\SystemSchedule\Details\SystemDetailsVisualElement.cs(36,16): error CS0122: 'SystemTreeViewItem' is inaccessible due to its protection level
```

Any ideas on how to resolve this? I assume it's a package versioning issue, but I don't know what versions might be compatible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely remove `com.unity.dots.editor` package from this list. This early dots editor tooling package became replaced by newer & built-in dots tools.

It is no longer needed since 2021.3 (I believe) and is likely to throw all kinds of errors in the newer editor versions.